# Clicking blank area in ListView vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I need to do a specific function (For example: disabling buttons) when I click on an empty area on `listview` and deselect an item:

[image]

I need to disable these controls marked in blue if I clicked on this blank area ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MouseDown event, use the HitInfo object to test what the user is clicking on:

```
Private Sub ListView1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) _
                                Handles ListView1.MouseDown
  Dim hti As ListViewHitTestInfo = ListView1.HitTest(e.Location)
  If hti.Location = ListViewHitTestLocations.None Then
    Button1.Enabled = False
  Else
    Button1.Enabled = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: MAN , REALLY THIS WORKS FINE , THANK YOU , but unfortunately it works when i double click on a blank area (or i mean when i click two times on the blank area , what should i do?)

Comment: MAN , I solved the problem by changing the other code to MouseClick INSTEAD OF SelectedIndexChanged and your code works perfectly , thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `SelectedIndexChangedEvent`

Disable if `SelectedIndex`= `-1`

Comment: hi , i understand the first line , but i don't understand the second line

Comment: Also ListView contains selected indices , it doesn't contain selectedIndex

Comment: Correct, you need to compare `SelectedIndices.Count = 0` or `SelectedItems.Count = 0`, this means there are no selected items.